# Devise, how to downcase emails on save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

right now users can log into devise with their email & password. Problem is that email is saved case sensitive which is confusing users.

Does Devise have a setting to downcase the email, something like downcase_keys?

I know I can manually do this with a before_save but I thought I had read devise had this as an option out of the box. I just can't find the doc on how to set it to downcase?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to configure it using `case_insensitive_keys` in `config/initializers/devise.rb` (see [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/generators/templates/devise.rb#L35)).

Comment: Intersting. You're right it is set and downcasing email. For some reason on trying to Sign In it isn't working. will report back

Comment: It's been added in the 1.2.rc, is your devise version recent enough? (I'd say yes if it's set, but it doesn't hurt to ask :-) )